# Need help with Least Squares Estimator

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, least-squares

I am interested in a One-Way ANOVA model:

[image]

I wrote the model out as [image] and got $X$ as a matrix that looks like:

[image]

Which is rank 2 (6 x 4 Matrix, so not full rank)

Does the least squares estimator for β = (µ, α1, α2)^T
exist? If it exists, is it unique? Why?

Comment: I see three parameters ($\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\mu$) in your model but four columns in $X.$  *What does that extra column represent??*

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint for your self-study question:

Is the design matrix full rank?  Also, please add the self-study tag.  What do you know about full-rank vs. non-full rank matrices and the estimability of the parameters?

Also, have you tried fitting a model with a full rank design matrix and one without a full rank design matrix in your statistical software program?  Some programs will generate a helpful warning that might help you answer this question.